# How to find what particular fonts are used for the system GTK theme in XUbuntu?

Tags: xorg, themes, xubuntu, fonts, gtk

Some non-native applications (say IntelliJ Idea) use ugly fonts instead of those the whole system does. I'd like to configure them manually but I don't know what particular font (there are so many...) and size to choose to match my system theme. Where can I look them up? I use XUbuntu 12.04 with XFCE 4.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 are using the droid fonts by default. If you changed them, you could look in settings manager, appearance and see which font you have set.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be a java application using the swing toolkit, it is best configured at that level.

Another point: During startup it said to me on the console that running it under openjdk isn't supported at all and something about rendering issues. Maybe your fonts will get better if you installed the oracle-jdk somehow.

Comment: I AM using Oracle JDK and it does not matter. I DO mean to fix the problem on that level, but I don't know what particular font to chose. I want to find out (but I don't know how) what font (the name) is used globally in the system (GTK) and chose the same (I know how) for the Java application.